# Where does Deadpool fall in the X-Men timeline?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, chronology, deadpool

When did the events of *Deadpool* take place in the X-Men timeline?

Surely *Deadpool* takes place in a quite recent time era as compared to *First Class* and it's sequel, but exactly where?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deadpool exists in the DOFP New Timeline, post Apocalypse. Modern Day, so 2016ish, putting it closer to the ***The Wolverine*** post-credit scene, where Xavier and Magneto show up to recruit Logan in the old Timeline. It is, *baring any future time travel schenanigans* <sup>*Note 1</sup>, about 8 years prior to the "good ending" that Logan wakes up to after the events of DOFP.

- 1973 DOFP Wolverine Stops Mystique from killing Trask, creates new timeline
- 1980 Apocalypse
- 1990s-2000s (*Some less crappy version of the original trilogy happens* ***maybe*** <sup>*Note 2</sup>)
- 2016 Deadpool
- 2017 Gambit (*Maybe*)
- 2023 DOFP Good Ending, the one where Wolverine wakes up to everyone still alive
- 202? New Mutants (*Maybe)
- 2029 Logan

[As Producer Simon Kinberg’s explains](http://screenrant.com/deadpool-x-men-origins-wolverine-connection/), Deadpool in the timeline:

> “[X-Men: Apocalypse] takes space chronologically before those other films, so it’s more like those films have to acknowledge this than we acknowledge Gambit, Deadpool, or Fantastic Four or anything else that exists within the sort of Fox/Marvel universe. But I work on all of those films in one capacity or another, either as a producer on all of them and as a writer on Fantastic Four and this movie, so I’m certainly aware of all the different stories we’re telling at the same time, and they all are part of a larger fabric now, and **so the world of Deadpool, the world of Gambit exists in a post-Days of Future Past post-Apocalypse world where all of these stories are the same as our shared history.** The same way that each of us of different ages knows about Nixon and knows about Reagan and knows about 9/11, **our fictitious events like the stadium dropping on the White House in 1973 is part of the world in which Gambit, Deadpool, Wolverine on forward exists.**”

[And then Deadpool's time setting](http://collider.com/new-mutants-movie-wolverine-3-simon-kinberg/):

> [Interviewer]: Does Deadpool take place in the X-Men/Fantastic Four universe of Fox? I know Colossus is in it.
>
> Kinberg: It takes place within the X-Men universe and references that universe. It’s not the same time period as our past tense X-Men movies, like First Class, Days of Future Past, and Apocalypse take place in the past and **Deadpool takes place in the present**, but it acknowledges everything that’s happened in those other movies and the universe, and like you said Colossus is in it and other characters from the X-Men world.

<sub>*Note 1: The sequel, Deadpool 2, a.k.a. Cable & Deadpool, revolves around the mutant Cable, the time traveling son of Scott Summers and Jean Grey and enemy to Apocalypse in the future, so expect more time travel shenanigans to screw the timeline up even more.</sub>

<sub>*Note 2: From the first interview above:</sub>

> <sub>Bryan Singer adds, “I rebooted the universe so now anything can happen,” with the caveat that their theory of time-travel and alternate universes revolve around immutability, in that things may differ, but **key events in every timeline will remain mostly similar**. Xavier will always form the X-Men, Wolverine will always enlist in Weapon X and get his adamantium claws, and Wade Wilson will always become a version of Deadpool.</sub>

Comment: I am pretty sure that they say "no new mutant was born in 20 years" or something along the line in Logan. Are you sure about that 2029 for Logan ? I didn't find anything with a quick search, I'd have to rewatch the movie

Answer (score -2):

If any of you don't get it Deadpool 2 obviously takes place sometime after the events of Logan as Wade is aware of Logans Death Wich means Deadpool 2 obviously takes place in either later 2029 or in the early 2030's since Logan took place in 2029 but because there seem to be more Mutants in existence than there should be then The Deadpool Movies are obviously in their own Stand alone Movie Universe and Timeline where he's just aware of the different actors and actresses of the various movies and their timelines remember this is something Deadpool is aware of in the Comics because he's so insane

Comment: " Wade is aware of Logans Death Wich means Deadpool 2 obviously takes place in either later 2029 "

One of Deadpool's key characteristics is that he is aware of the real world, the things that take place in it and his position in it. Therefore his referencing the events of Logan may mean nothing more than he was aware that the film exists in our world. He's done the same to Ferris Bueller's Day Off and Green Lantern, and I'm very sure they didnt happen in the X-Men universe.