# How did this character get so big in Deadpool 2?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2, x-men-the-last-stand

In the *X-Men 3: The Last Stand*, the character Juggernaut is shown as the same height as a typical human.

[image]

In *Deadpool 2*, which makes a lot of references to X-Men, Juggernaut is several feet taller and much larger overall. (I'll include a picture if I can find one.)

Are the two movies supposed to exist in the same universe? Does Juggernaut grow over time? Is this a reimagining of Juggernaut? Is the *Deadpool 2* Juggernaut more in alignment with the original character from the comics?

Comment: It is not the same character, the one in X-Men 3 was the [Juggernaut Bitch](https://youtu.be/tqtqEZqGg5A?t=49s), the one in Deadpool 2 is the Juggernaut.

Comment: Two words:  Prison food.

Comment: “Are the two movies supposed to exist in the same universe?” These timelines are *so* confusing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Are the two movies supposed to exist in the same universe?

### Yes...and No

The "universe" is not exactly stable and has been rebooted and recreated a few times as described in [**this Deadpool/X-Men Timeline question & answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47738/where-does-deadpool-fall-in-the-x-men-timeline).

> > Bryan Singer adds, “I rebooted the universe so now anything can happen,” with the caveat that their theory of time-travel and alternate universes revolve around immutability, in that things may differ, but key events in every timeline will remain mostly similar. Xavier will always form the X-Men, Wolverine will always enlist in Weapon X and get his adamantium claws, and Wade Wilson will always become a version of Deadpool.

---

> Does Juggernaut grow over time? Is this a reimagining of Juggernaut? Is the Deadpool 2 Juggernaut more in alignment with the original character from the comics?

You could call it a re-imagining but the Deadpool "version" is considerable closer to the comic version that the Vinnie Jones portrayal.

From Marvel's [**comic wiki**](http://marvel.com/universe/Juggernaut_(Cain_Marko)) his height is **9'5"** (**2.87 m**) and weight **1,900 lbs** (**862 kg**).

[image]

Comment: When I wear a red tank top, I look just like that.

Comment: @BrettFromLA you'll think, but in reality you'll just be looks like adam sandler with red tank top, singing a song with a guitar ;)

Comment: @Vishwa LOL true!

Comment: When did he get so big in the comics?  He used to be a really large guy able to sit at a bar without too much attention if he was not in armor like in Uncanny X-men 183.

Comment: @SDH **He used to be a really large guy able to sit at a bar without too much attention if he was not in armor** , But as you said **if** he already was a large guy, then he surely get attention. Although what I can't understand is, you asking When did he get so big, while in next sentence you saying He used to be a really large guy

Comment: @Vishwa There is a big difference between 'really large guy' and freakishly huge.  We see really large guys every day, no one has ever seen someone as large as the stats listed on that picture.

Comment: @SDH I just rephrased what you've said above. you said **He used to be a really large guy** and **When did he get so big**. So what it tells is he was already huge and you still wondering why he became huge. *Anyways, his size in comics is not valid here, this is about the movies.*

Comment: @Vishwa Congratulations about making a point about the wording of my question instead of the content.  You are intentionally being obtuse for no apparent reason.  Just for you - 'When did he get so freakishly huge in the comics? He used to be a really large guy but still able to sit at a bar without too much attention if he was not in armor like in Uncanny X-men 183.  Please note I am asking about the comics because the picture and stats in the post I responded to are from the comics.'

Comment: Regardless, this is *irrelevant* to the question being asked. Juggernaut in DP2 is a re-imagining of the character...

Comment: @SDH When you are asking something from a stranger/from internet, please be clear as much as possible. others can't understand everything but only can speculate something from the words you've put out. as Paulie_D mentioned, comic illustrations are off topic. To answer your question anyway, comics and movies are different media, each can have different interpretation on same moment. Wolverine doesn't wear yellow, Thor is not very muscular 8ft tall guy, cyclops doesn't wear red, Jarvis is an AI.. list goes on

Comment: @SDH https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ can take your question about the comics.